# HttpEventType.UploadProgress does not come from Asp.NET MVC

Tags: angular, file, asp.net-web-api, upload, progress

My problem is that when I upload file with Angular Progress to ASP.NET Web-API service then i can listen to progress events `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` successfully locally.

But when I host it with HTTPS at remote server Windows Server I'm not receiving those events.

Should I change something in web.config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems

1) EDGE does not support such events. Microsoft probably will fix it if there will be much votes for fixing this bug
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12224510/

2) During AOT compilation each service is created once per LAZY module. That's why subscriptions on service in one module did not get events from other module same service.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the AOT compilation deal, and how can be fixed to get the upload event ?

Comment: To ensure that service is created once - provideIn: root attribute to be supplied in @Injectable attribute. Next, EDGE is to be replaced with Chrome clone in September.